# Как отмасштабировать граф нарисованный с помощью graphviz в jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, graphviz

Пытаюсь отрисовать довольно объёмный граф с множеством связей и узлов с помощью python библиотеки graphviz. Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли отмасштабировать граф так, чтобы он влезал в окно вывода JupyterNotebook, без появления полос горизонтальных и вертикальных полос прокрутки.

Answer (score 0):

Пофиксил используя HTML (из IPython) и Digraph из Graphviz:

```
HTML(digraph.pipe(format='svg').decode())
```

где digraph - экземпляр класса Digraph, с хранящимся внутри графом.